# plotting only selected class from multiple CSV files in R (ggplot)

Tags: r, csv, plot, ggplot2

Let's say I have imported 2(or more) CSV files having similar columns. Let's say I have "A", "B" and "class" columns in each of the CSV files but the values are different. Let's suppose my dataset in one CSV file is:

```
A B class
1 2  A
2 3  B
4 1  A
3 7  C
4 5  A
.....
```

Let's say 2nd CSVs dataset be:

```
A   B  class
10  20  A
20  10  C
40  10  B
30  17  A
14  15  A
.....
```

and so on for other CSVs..

Initially I have made ggplots for individual CSV files using "A" and "B". Now I want to plot all the CSV files in a single plot using only one class at a time i.e., Let's say I want to plot for only class A for all the CSVs in a single plot.

I did plot all the files in a single plot but now I want to plot it class wise..

Can any one tell how can I do this thing?

Comment: Just subset? The hard part is plotting all the files in a single plot---you say you've already done this. If you show some of your code for doing this it should be a simple modification to only plot the A class.

Comment: @Gregor I have put all the CSV files in a single folder and then call all the files.

Comment: That's great. Could you **show some of your code**?

Comment: @Gregor I have updated. You can look into it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join all your CSVs into one dataframe and `subset` and plot?

e.g.

```
csv1 <- read.csv(...)
csv2 <- read.csv(...)

bigcsv <- rbind(csv1, csv2)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(subset(bigscv, class == 'A'), aes(...)) + ...
```

The key is simply to `subset(bigcsv, class=='A')`.

You can also use `rbind.fill` to `rbind` a big list of dataframes.

Comment: `csvs <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)` will make `csvs[[i]]` the ith csv. Then as mentioned, `bigcsv <- rbind.fill(csvs)` and continue.